# Azure MobileServices Push Notifcation from Database table

Tags: azure, windows-8, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

This is my scenario, I have created a worker role on Azure and created an SQL Database and a Mobile Service.

The database is shared between my worker role and my mobile service.

My worker role fetches information from the web and if it finds something I want to send a push notification using my mobile service.

My question is, how can I send a push notification of the first item in my table when my worker role inserts the data into the table?

My applications is a Windows 8 application

*UPDATE: Trying to follow this guide but always resulting in internal server error 500 when trying to post

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/using-azure-mobile-services-in-your-web-apps-through-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: Take a look to this tutorial: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-dotnet/. Note that, to make things work, you need to insert data from your worker role using Mobile Services API, making a REST request.

Comment: im trying to follow this guide, but always getting internal server error when trying to post to my table http://www.strathweb.com/2012/09/using-azure-mobile-services-in-your-web-apps-through-asp-net-web-api/  any ideas why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the REST API as suggested by Marco, or if the logic in your worker role is not that complex, you can move the push notification to the Windows Azure Mobile Services Scheduler instead:

have a look at this: [Send Push Notifications at Periodic Interval with the Mobile Services Scheduler](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Send-Push-Notifications-at-cd0ccd48)